# Extracting text from multiple XML files with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, extract

I have at least 500 XML files on which I need to find text and phrases in a language other than English.

As these XML files are populated with a lot of tags and not much text, I thought that one way to solve my problem was to extract the text from these files in order to find the sentences in other languages, using beautifulsoup.

I've already started but I'm stuck, here is what i've donne until now :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import glob

for filename in glob.glob("*.xml"):
    with open(filename) as open_file:
        content = open_file.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
        textExtracted = soup.findAll(text=True)
        print(' '.join(textExtracted))
```

To find and know which text comes from which file it would be necessary to have the name of the file before the extraction, how I could do that? There is a library to use for this?

Could you help me ?

Comment: If you need to keep track of the filename, why don't you create a dictionary and assign text to each filename key? Example: `dict_xml[filename] = ' '.join(textExtracted)`

Comment: Yes that's a good idea. But now my script is not working is not printing smt